# Is there a way to let Layout Elements auto-rescaling instead of auto-resizing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, autolayout

I have an empty `GameObject` with `Grid Layout Group` in it.

And several `Sprite` children gameobjects with `Layout Element`s in them.

I noticed that the `Grid Layout Group` will "resize" them according to its setups.

But unfortunately, the `Sprite` is unaffected by the "size", it is affected by the "scales".

And I can't find any options in neither `Grid Layout Group` nor `Layout Element` allowing me to set it as auto-rescaling instead of auto-resizing.

Nor could I find any options in `Sprite Renderer` to let it "autofit" to its size.

I tried to add a script in the child objects rescaling them through code:

```
RectTransform rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.localScale = rt.sizeDelta;
rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(1, 1);
```

But for some reason, all the `sizeDelta`s are all become (0,0) when it was assigned to the `localScale`.

And the funny thing is, when I check it in the inspector after running, all the sizes in the `Rect Transform` are what it supposed to be!

(So the result becomes: `sizeDelta` unchanged, `localScale` becomes (0,0,0).)

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me how to fix it?

Or maybe there are some options or other components I could add to the child objects to let them auto-rescale?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Layout groups](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIAutoLayout.html) are designed to be used with UI Elements so instead of sprite renderer you're expected to use [Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image.html) that uses rect transform to control its size. For game objects using sprite renderer you're better off using [grid](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Grid.html) component or creating custom component.

Now if you're making games like match three games you'll have to decide whether you want to use UI Elements for the tiles/orbs/fruits or sprites with grid or some sort of custom component. Both of these have their pros and cons.